# How to make a database file with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a simple todo list with flask. When I run the command `from app import db` to make the .db file for the database I got an error that says that the flask module is not installed. The module is installed and works when I try running the code without the database lines. What am I doing wrong?

Here is all of the code and the error message: [image]

Answer (score 0):

To create a database file with the code above you can import db from app in your python prompt and call `db.create_all()`function to create the database file as below:

```py
>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

And please correct `db.model` to `db.Model` or you will get an error.

Comment: I did capitalize model. I was trying to `from app import db` in my python prompt which was giving me the error that said flask is not installed.

Comment: Did you try re-initialising your venv.

Comment: If any  of the above steps doesn't work please refer to my second answer that i posted.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers does not work you can add a seperate `schema.sql` file corresponding to the models in your python code and try creating the database file like below:

schema.sql:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Todo;

CREATE TABLE Todo(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            content TEXT NOT NULL,
            date_created DATE NOT NULL
);
```

And then go to your terminal in your project directory, activate your venv and type in the following commands:

```sh
sqlite3 database.db < schema.sql
```

And your database file would get created. Now you can connect and use it like a normal database from your code.And you wouldn't need to install anything since sqlite3 already comes with python.
If for any reason sqlite3 is not installed just run any of the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```